# Injectable component in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, ag-grid

I am working on angular 7 app and the design is like, I have footer component at the bottom on my app and inside the footer I have ag-grid.

What I am doing is if user perform any operation like load any data or load any report, I add new line in ag-grid to show the status.

What I want to do is use only single instance of this component available through out application and this same single object should be inserted into another component if they request using DI. So when they add message to this messagewindow, then all message should be added to same window.

I tried with @Injectable but no luck.

Here is the code, I have written for messageBoxComponent...

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-box',
  templateUrl: './message-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-box.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class MessageBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  public newCount = 1;
  public gridOptions: GridOptions;
  constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
      rowData: this.createRowData(),
      columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
      onGridReady: () => {
        this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      },
      rowHeight: 30, // recommended row height for material design data grids,
      headerHeight: 30
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public AddMessage(newrow) {
    var newItem = newrow;
    this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: [newItem] });
  }

  public PostMessage(message: string, comp: string) {
    var newData = {
      Source: comp,
      Datetime: this.GetCurrentDateTime(),
      Category: "Information",
      Message: message
    };
    this.AddMessage(newData);
  }

  public PostWarning(message: string, comp: string) {
    var newData = {
      Source: comp,
      Datetime: this.GetCurrentDateTime(),
      Category: "Information",
      Message: message
    };
    this.AddMessage(newData);
  }

  public PostError(message: string, comp: string) {
    var newData = {
      Source: comp,
      Datetime: this.GetCurrentDateTime(),
      Category: "Information",
      Message: message
    };
    this.AddMessage(newData);
  }


  private createColumnDefs() {
    return [
      {
        headerName: "Source",
        field: "Source",
        cellEditor: "sliderEditor",
        width: 50,
        cellEditorParams: {
          thumbLabel: true
        }

      },
      {
        headerName: "Datetime",
        field: "Datetime",
        cellEditor: "sliderEditor",
        width: 50,
        cellEditorParams: {
          thumbLabel: true
        }

      },
      {
        headerName: "Category",
        field: "Category",
        cellEditor: "sliderEditor",
        width: 50,
        cellEditorParams: {
          thumbLabel: true
        }

      },
      {
        headerName: "Message",
        field: "Message",
        cellEditor: "sliderEditor",
        cellEditorParams: {
          thumbLabel: true
        }

      }
    ];
  }

  private createRowData() {
    return [
      {
        Source: "HSAS",
        Datetime: this.GetCurrentDateTime(),
        Category: "Information",
        Message: "Application Initilized successfully."
      },

    ];
  }

  private GetCurrentDateTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return date + ' ' + time;
  }
}
```

html

```
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" class="ag-theme-dark" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Gridoption never initialized in components.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your component as an [entryComponent](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components) , this way you can create your component without declaring it in your HTML, after that you can pass data to it with a shared service between your component A and component B, so the results will be rendered in your entryComponent which will be instantiated only once